# How to avoid reconnections with socket.io-client and React app?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I tried to connect React client to my Socket.IO server. I noticed Socket.IO client reconnects every +/- 5s. When I try do the same thing with vanilla html/js simple app everything works crrectly.

Inside React component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const s = getChatClient();
}, []);
```

Inside socket.io-client module:

```
var chatClient;

export function getChatClient(
  token = "secret"
) {
  if (!chatClient) {
    chatClient = io("http://localhost:5000/chat", {
      query: {
        token,
      },
    });
    chatClient
      .on("connect", () => {
        chatClient.emit("textMessage", "123cos");
      })
      .on("hello", (msg) => {
        console.log("12");
      });
  }
  return chatClient;
}
```

BTW: I know I can do it export const etc (I've changed to this version becouse I thought it'll help).

I tried different ways to resolve this problem, but I got in stuck. Any ideas?

Log from the server when I open html/js simple client:

```
15:30:00 User Ilona connected to the socket.io server on /
```

and when I quit:

```
  15:29:12 User Ilona disconnected
```

With React App:

```
  15:30:00 User Ilona connected to the socket.io server on '/'
  15:30:05 User Ilona disconnected 
  15:30:10 User Ilona connected to the socket.io server on '/' 
  15:30:15 User Ilona disconnected 
  15:30:20 User Ilona connected to the socket.io server on '/' 
  15:30:25 User Ilona disconnected
```

The problem isn't related with component rerender or something like this.

I'm working on MacOS Big Sur.

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating, and then consuming from a context:

SocketContext.jsx :

```js
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const SocketContext = createContext();

export default function SocketContextProvider(props) {
  const [sock, setSocket] = useState(null);

  let socket = async () => {
    if (sock) {
      return Promise.resolve(sock); // If already exists resolve
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let newSock = io('URL'),
        {
          query: {
            // Options
          },
        }; // Try to connect
      
      let didntConnectTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        reject();
      }, 15000) // Reject if didn't connect within 15 seconds

      newSock.once('connect', () => {
        clearTimeout(didntConnectTimeout); // It's connected so we don't need to keep waiting 15 seconds
        setSocket(newSock); // Set the socket
        resolve(newSock); // Return the socket
      })
    });
  };

  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={{ socket }}>
      {props.children}
    </SocketContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Component.jsx :

```js
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { SocketContext } from './SocketContext.jsx';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const { socket } = useContext(SocketContext);
  const [sock, setSock] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket()
      .then((resultSocket) => setSock(resultSocket))
      .catch(() => {
      /* Catch any errors here */
        console.log('Couldn\'t connect the socket!')
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <code>I'm a context consumer...</code>
    </div>
  );
}
```